# Web API not returning a specific List of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am interested in a BOOKS entities from edm framework only.
However I am getting some other entities along with BOOKS entity.

Here is my web API controller

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    private MyECommerceDBEntities db = new MyECommerceDBEntities();

    // GET: api/Books
    [ResponseType(typeof(BOOKS))]
    public IQueryable<BOOKS> GetBOOKS()
    {
        return db.BOOKS.OrderByDescending(x => x.BOOKID).Skip(977).Take(5).AsQueryable<BOOKS>();
    }
}
```

Here is my returned JSON string

```
[{"$id":"1","PRODUCTS":{"$id":"2","MOVIES":[],"ORDERITEMS":[],"PRODUCTDETAILS":[],"SUBCATEGORIES":{"$id":"3","CATEGORIES":{"$id":"4","SUBCATEGORIES":[{"$ref":"3"},{"$id":"5","CATEGORIES":{"$ref":"4"},"PRODUCTS":[],"SUBCATEGORYID":2,"CATEGORYID":1,"SUBCATEGORY":"Kindle Edition","DESCRIPTION":"Kindle EBook"}],"CATEGORYID":1,"CATEGORY":"Books","DESCRIPTION":"Books"},"PRODUCTS":[{"$ref":"2"},{"$id":"6","MOVIES":[],"ORDERITEMS":[],"PRODUCTDETAILS":[],"SUBCATEGORIES":{"$ref":"3"},"REVIEWS":[],"SELLERS_PRODUCTS":[],"CART":[],"BOOKS":[{"$id":"7","PRODUCTS":{"$ref":"6"},"BOOKID":1,"PRODUCTID":1964,"ISBN10":"ISBN-10: 1-934356-43","ISBN13":"ISBN-13: 978-1-93435","BOOKNAME":"Agile Coaching","DESCRIPTION":"","AUTHOR":null,"PUBLISHER":null,"PAGES":"236","BOOKIMAGE":"Agile `Coaching.jpeg","PUBLISHEDDATE":null}],"PRODUCTID":1964,"SUBCATEGORYID":1,"NAME":"Agile Coaching","DESCRIPTION":"","PRICE":0.0},{"$id":"8","MOVIES":[],"ORDERITEMS":[],"PRODUCTDETAILS":[],"SUBCATEGORIES":{"$ref":"3"},"REVIEWS":[],"SELLERS_PRODUCTS":[],"CART":[],"BOOKS":`
```

Comment: It is  probably including navigation properties. Try to avoid returning entities directly from EF. create a DTO model with only the information you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  probably including navigation properties of the entity when it is being serialized in the response.

Try to avoid returning entities directly from Entity Framework over the wire.

Create a DTO model with only the relevant information you want returned to the caller.

Simple example

```
//Book model
public class Book {
    public int BookKId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }
    public string ISBN13 { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    //...other properties
}
```

And have the entity mapped to the model when returning from the action

```
 // GET: api/Books
[ResponseType(typeof(Book[]))]
public IHttpActionResult GetBOOKS() {
    var books = db.BOOKS.OrderByDescending(x => x.BOOKID).Skip(977).Take(5)
    .Select(book => new Book {
        BookKId = book.BOOKID,
        BookName = book.BOOKNAME
        //...other properties
    })
    .ToArray();
    return Ok(books);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More over to above answer from Nkosi, here is the explanation different types of loading in EF Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data